# generate .m3u8/hls live stream thumbnails/frames of videos flutter

Tags: java, ios, flutter, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am looking for a cleaner way of generating a thumbnail for a live stream in flutter with `.m3u8` links.

I have tried searching on the plugins section, but I couldn't get any solution for the above issue.